# I don't like the way I have solved this problem. How could I have done this better?

Tags: python, precision, cs50

I have submitted my project, I just want to understand for future usage. My code passes the tests CS50 run on it. I don't like how I've had to add something to the values to deal with floating point imprecision. Is there a better way so I know for the future? The issue I am talking about is adding ".001" to each value.

```
from cs50 import get_float

while True:
    change = get_float("How much change is owed? ")
    if change > 0:
        break
q = (change/.25) + 0.001
if q >= 1:
    change = change - (int(q) / 4)
d = (change / .1) + 0.001
if d >= 1:
    change = change - (int(d) / 10)
n = (change / .05) + 0.001
if n >= 1:
    change = change - (int(n) / 20)
p = (change / .01) + 0.001

coins = int(q)+int(d)+int(n)+int(p)
print(coins)
```

Below is the specification for the project:
Specification
Write, in a file called cash.py, a program that first asks the user how much change is owed and then spits out the minimum number of coins with which said change can be made. You can do this exactly as you did in Problem Set 1, except that your program this time should be written in Python, and you should assume that the user will input their change in dollars (e.g., 0.50 dollars instead of 50 cents).

Use get_float from the CS50 Library to get the user’s input and print to output your answer. Assume that the only coins available are quarters (25¢), dimes (10¢), nickels (5¢), and pennies (1¢).
We ask that you use get_float so that you can handle dollars and cents, albeit sans dollar sign. In other words, if some customer is owed $9.75 (as in the case where a newspaper costs 25¢ but the customer pays with a $10 bill), assume that your program’s input will be 9.75 and not $9.75 or 975. However, if some customer is owed $9 exactly, assume that your program’s input will be 9.00 or just 9 but, again, not $9 or 900. Of course, by nature of floating-point values, your program will likely work with inputs like 9.0 and 9.000 as well; you need not worry about checking whether the user’s input is “formatted” like money should be.

If the user fails to provide a non-negative value, your program should re-prompt the user for a valid amount again and again until the user complies.

Incidentally, so that we can automate some tests of your code, we ask that your program’s last line of output be only the minimum number of coins possible: an integer followed by a newline.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could immediately switch to integer arithmetic by converting the input to number of cents (instead of dollar). Then you can use integer division, and also the modulo operator is interesting here:

```
change = round(change * 100)  # Switch from dollars to cents

q = change // 25
change %= 25
d = change // 10
change %= 10
n = change // 5
change %= 5
p = change

coins = q + d + n + p
```

And you can avoid some code repetition by putting this in a loop:

```
change = round(change * 100)  # Work with cents

coins = 0
for coin in 25, 10, 5, 1:
    coins += change // coin
    change %= coin
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. You've given me a lot to think about and work with. I got overly concerned with this being my first time writing python and I can now see the wood through the trees